# Non Sequential Serial Numbering

Tags: excel, nonsequential

I am a newbie to function writing in Excel and really need help urgently.I need to assign serial numbers with uneven increments. For Example I have a column B that contains some names of customers in bold and some are unbold. I want write a function that checks for bold text in Column B and assign a serial number (e.g 1, 2,..) to it in adjacent column A. The out below is what I desire:

```
Column A        Column B

1               **Peter**

                Micheal

                George


2               **Julia**

3               **Sam**
```

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to check if the text is bold using formulas. You will have to put some kind of flag on the lines where you want a serial number. For example, if we put "1" in column C next to Peter, Julia and Sam, the formula in A2 would be `=IF(C2=1;MAX(A$1:A1;1))` (then you copy it down on the other lines).

Comment: Thank You! the MAX function helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Named Range - XLM workaround

1. Define a new range name,`IsRightCellBold` as `=GET.CELL(20,INDIRECT("RC2",FALSE))`. This will return True if the cell to the immediate right is either all Bold or has the first character as Bold
2. Enter this formula in A2 `=IF(IsRightCellBold,MAX($A$1:A1)+1,"")` and copy down

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much brettdj! that completely solved my problem :)